# How do I find out the pixel depth of my graphic card?

Tags: command-line, x11

Is there a command that can tell me which my graphic card is and its pixel-depth? I am running vncserver and I would like to learn which is the best parameter for pixeldepth (-depth).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`xdpyinfo`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xdpyinfo.1.html) gives you this information. A display can support multiple depths.

```
xdpyinfo | awk '$1=="depth" && sub(/,$/, "", $2) {print $2}'
```

If your display consists of multiple screens, they may support multiple depths.

```
xdpyinfo | awk '
    $1=="screen" {screen = substr($2, 2, length($2)-2)}
    $1=="depths" {$1=$2=""; print screen, $0}
'
```

You won't get any benefit from telling VNC to use a larger value, and some applications might misbehave if VNC isn't using a value in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong suspicion that option is more for bandwidth reasons than different graphics cards: my understanding is that all but the most ancient graphics cards use 24 bits for color per pixel, though I guess really high-end ones may use more. Reducing this in VNC may make the resulting image look worse but may make your VNC sessions more responsive.

Source: messing with VNC, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth

Comment: I am connecting to a computing cluster, the graphic card could be not very sofisticated, because the system is aimed mainly at computing. I wanted to understand if the system was 16 or 24, because I am having trouble with an application that only works with 24-bit cards, and I am trying to understand if the problem is with the pixel-depth I use in the connection or if the card is effectively 16-bit.

Comment: Ohhh! That's a harder problem than I thought! If I recall correctly you can add some verbosity to VNC's output that will tell you what pixel depth is being used, even from the client end. May depend on the client.

Also, I'm pretty sure VNC requires an X server to be running as well: it's possible that X is configured to use a lower color depth. I've definitely noticed banding on one of my Linux machines that I didn't see when booting Windows.

Comment: Note that all of this means VNC could conceivably report 24 bits when it's really 16 at the Xorg level. Try http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/display_settings.php to see what your browser thinks the color depth is. My suspicion is that the X is configured to use a 16-bit depth, but where to find that information and how to change it may depend on your distro/Unix flavor as well as custom configurations.

Comment: well, I launched vncserver with depth 24 (that failed earlier for some reason), and now the application works, so this was really a problem with the connection itself rather than the card, I didn't expect! Still don't know the properties of my graphic card, though, and lspci doesn't work.