# Colour codes for 88 colours

Tags: colors, hex

I am looking at the colour codes

Have seen the 88 colour, any idea what bit length is used for 88 colours?

```
3-Bit  (2^3)  | 8     | 8  (Primary) (000 to 111)
4-Bit  (2^4)  | 16    | 16 (Basic)   (0000 to 1111)
              | 88    | 16 (Basic) + 4×4×4 (Cube) + 8  (Grey)
8-Bit  (2^8)  | 256   | 16 (Basic) + 6×6×6 (Cube) + 24 (Grey)

24-Bit (2^24) | RGB-Code has 24-Bit Format (Bits 0 to 23)
16,777,216    | 8 Bits Per Colour Channel  (2^8=256)
              | Red[7:0]Grn[7:0]Blu[7:0] (256^3)
              | Hex FF is 255 (256 = 16*16)
```

Comment: "*The* 88 colour codes" ? Where are these defined ? The X system names several hundred colours, for example. If somebody has chosen a pleasing palette of 88 colours, and given those ones specific names, they are just going to be a subset of the 24-bit 16.7 million possibles. The hardware runs one of the colour systems you researched for yourself (almost all 24-bit this century).

Comment: You are correct.  In Emacs I found `((class color) (min-colors 88)` occurs frequently.  Regarding 24-bit, there are not really 16.7 million colours available, right?.  When a colour hex-code is not supported, tools like emacs automatically and transparently finds the closest color that is supported, and uses that.

Comment: Your eyes probably can't distinguish 16.7 millon colours (conventional wisdom says up to around 1 million), but I see no reason to doubt that your equipment can display 16.7 million different colours. (You'll need high class equipment to distinguish some of them from each other)

Comment: Correct, one cannot distinguish.  Many different RGB codes  result in the same colour.  Yes, I have depth 24, but was reading about the archaic others (8,16,88,256).

Comment: Quite a lot of LCD displays actually only have 6 bits of colour depth per channel; they dither down from whatever they claim to support. So it’s possible you can’t distinguish different colours because your monitor can’t display them differently!

Comment: 7-bit in total, yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out the pixel depth of my graphic card?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77282/how-do-i-find-out-the-pixel-depth-of-my-graphic-card)

Answer (score 2):

88-colors uses *indexed* colors, i.e., a *color palette*.  Indexed colors use a *colormap* which is what the name implies: a lookup table used to map colors onto the display server's available resolution.

While it is possible to implement the palette using red/green/blue, normally it is not treated in that manner.  As I noted on [*bug-ncurses*](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ncurses/2020-03/msg00025.html) a couple of years ago, the 88-color palette's savings over 256-colors are not in the number of bits used to represent the indexed-color (which is relevant to the *depth* of the display shown by `xdpyinfo`), but in the size of the colormap:

```
On Thu, Mar 19, 2020 at 03:59:08AM -0400, Nick Black wrote:
> [ hey there! this is really more of an xterm question than an
>   ncurses question, but the former doesn't appear to have a
>   mailing list, and last time i asked a question here, i got great
>   answers. so...i hope not to offend ]
> 
> While doing some research for a book I'm writing[0], I came
> across the support for 88 color palettes in xterm and (later)
> at least rxvt. Patch #115 [1] appears to have added the 88-color
> support to xterm (the NCURSES NEWS file mentions 88-color
> terminfo sources by 1999). The Xterm FAQ mentions:
> 
> "88-colors (using the same control sequence) came next, to
>  reduce the amount of memory needed. XTerm stores both foreground
>  and background color indexes for each cell on the screen. That
>  is two bytes, which doubled the amount of memory used by xterm
>  for the scrollback. Reducing that to a single byte allowed a
>  similar scheme using a 4x4x4 cube and a proportionately shorter
>  grayscale ramp."
> 
> My question(s) is(are):
> 
>  (1) How is this a "single byte"? For 88 colors, you need 7

that's an editorial blunder :-(

I don't see email from Steve Wall for that issue (diskspace was a lot more
expensive in 1999), and when expanding the faq in 2016, I probably noticed his
comment which I'd conveyed into the changelog about allocating memory and
misread that into the number of bytes.

Both 88/256 use 2 bytes for color in the character cell, but the color map
would be different (88*88 versus 256*256 combinations).
 
> i guess my question boils down to: what made 88 more appealing
> than either 64 or 128? were 88 colors encodable in fewer than 7
> net bits? did this mechanism not stretch to 96 colors?

The size of the colormap is probably the main issue.
The X server has a lookup table for colors which has limited size.

I recall that running Netscape would cause the colormap to be mostly
allocated for that application, making the colors unavailable to
other applications.

Beyond that, the 88-color layout was intended to fit with the same
idea as in 256-colors: 16-color set, along with a cube and then a
grayscale set.  I suppose one could come up with a 5x5x5 scheme:

        88      157     256
        -------------------
        16      16      16      ANSI/AIX
        64      125     216     cube
        8       16      24      grayscale "ramp"

But the savings in the colormap wouldn't be as much:

        colors  size    bits
        88      7744    13
        157     24649   15
        256     65536   16
                ^^^important!
```

That is, the 88-color palette requires less than one eighth as large a colormap as the 256-color palette, which seems like a reasonable tradeoff for reducing the number of colors to about a third.